# SwiftUI: Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time

Tags: swift, swiftui, websocket

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI, and I'm trying to build a chatroom.
When I send message to the app, the new message won't display and I got a warning in the terminal saying "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time."

```
import SwiftUI
import SocketIO

struct ChatMessage: Hashable {
    var message: String
    var MatchImg: String
    var isMe: Bool

}

class ChatMessageList: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [ChatMessage]
    
    init(list: [ChatMessage]) {
        self.list = list
    }
    
    func addItem(item: ChatMessage) {
        list.append(item)
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

struct MessageView: View {
    @State private var showMenu: Bool = false
    @StateObject var messages = ChatMessageList(list: [
        ChatMessage(message: "Hello world", MatchImg:"ye",isMe: true),
        ChatMessage(message: "Hello world", MatchImg:"ye",isMe: false)
    ])
    
    @State private var composedMessage: String = ""
    let roomID: String
    let userID: String
    let otherUser: String
    
    private var socket: SocketIOClient
    private var manager: SocketManager
    
    init(roomID: String, userID: String, otherUser: String) {
        self.roomID = roomID
        self.userID = userID
        self.otherUser = otherUser
        
        self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!, config: [.log(false), .compress])
        self.socket = self.manager.defaultSocket
        
        self.socket.connect()
        
        self.addHandlers()
        
        
    }

    func addHandlers() {
        self.socket.on("chat message") { data, ack in
            let messageText = data[0]

            let newMessage = ChatMessage(message: messageText as! String, MatchImg: "ye", isMe: false)
            addMessage(message: newMessage)
            
//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                self.messages.list.append(newMessage)
//            }
            
           
        }
    }
    
    func addMessage(message: ChatMessage) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            messages.addItem(item: message)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center){
                    //omitted
                }
                
                List{
                    ForEach(messages.list, id: \.self) { msg in
                        ChatRow(chatMessage: msg)
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                            .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    }
                    
                }
                .padding(0)
                .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
                .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
                
                
                
                
                HStack {
                    TextField("Message...", text: $composedMessage).frame(minHeight: CGFloat(36))
                        .padding(.horizontal,12)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                    Button("Send"){
                        Task {
                            self.socket.emit("message", roomID, composedMessage)
                            self.messages.addItem(item: ChatMessage(message: composedMessage, MatchImg: "ye", isMe: true))
                            print(self.messages)
                            self.composedMessage = ""
                        }
                    }
                    Button("add") {
                        showMenu.toggle()
                    }
                    Button(action: {}){
                        Image("person.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        
                    }
                }.padding(20)
                    .task{
                        print(self.socket.status)
                        self.socket.emit("identify", userID)
                        
                        self.socket.emit("subscribe", roomID, otherUser)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ChatRow : View {
    var chatMessage: ChatMessage
    var body: some View {
        if !chatMessage.isMe {
            
            HStack {
                // omitted
            }
        }
        else {
             // omitted
       }

    }
}
```

I've tried

- Using `DispatchQueue.main.async`
- Write a separate function to add new messages (`addMessage()`)
- Write a function in the class `ChatMessageList`

I printed the state object after adding a new item, but there's no new message.
But all the above functions seems to work just fine when sending new message.

Comment: That error is exactly what it says somewhere you have a `@StateObject` and it is not in a `View` it doesn't seem to be here since you only have 1 and it is in `MessageView`

Comment: I see you have not taken my advice to your previous question when you used another fake account:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77671221/view-not-updated-when-received-message-from-socket-building-a-chat-in-swiftui and a different name `saladboi`.

 Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't init objects like the SocketManager inside a `View` struct and you can't use `DispatchQueue.main.async` in `View` structs either. `View` data structs are just simple values that are generated, differed and destroyed. So if you create objects in them it's considered a memory leak and a dispatch async will return onto some old lost `View` struct if it does at all.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a separate controller to initialize SocketManager and things worked out.

Comment: Please upvote answers that help